# firebasejs 4.0 does not work with angular cli project

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli

I can not integrate firebasejs 4.0 to angular cli project, my steps are

```
ng new firebasetest
cd firebasetest
ng serve  ==> works fine
```

just add

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

to index.html and run ng serve
got errors

```
TypeError: __webpack_require__(16) is not a function. (In '__webpack_require__(16)(function(){
  rApply(function(){});
})', '__webpack_require__(16)' is an instance of Object)
websocket.js:11TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'process.env.NODE_ENV')
```

How to fix this?

Comment: But [angularfire2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularfire2) works.

Comment: angularfire2 is based on "firebase": "^3.6.6",

Comment: Don't include `firebase` like this. Instead, include it with `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'` or the equivalent.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! But why this works?

Answer (score 0):

Supose you have had inserted the complete snippet code below, following the documentation, anyway not working for me, too! can't get the reference from firebase on angular 4 cli app, maybe could be a typing setup, that I do not accomplished.

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Comment: I found the errors only happened in dev mode, using ng serve --prod is fine.

Comment: I did this work, installing via npm then, add the snipet configuration above on app.component.ts constructor, doing "import * as firebase from 'firebase'". works fine with ng serve dev.